# Verificar se todos items do subarray estão com status "false"

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho um array(pai) e dentro dele tenho mais dois arrays. Os arrays filhos existem uma propriedade `status`. Gostaria de saber como consigo validar se todos items do array estão com a propriedade `status` como `false`.

```
let materials = [
  {
    group: 'A',
    data: [
      { id: 1, name: 'PC Dell', materialGroup: 'A', amount: 1, status: false },
      { id: 2, name: 'Mouse', materialGroup: 'A', amount: 2, status: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    group: 'B',
    data: [
      { id: 3, name: 'Teclado', materialGroup: 'B', amount: 1, status: false }
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O método [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) verifica se *todos* os elementos de um array satisfazem um predicado. Veja o exemplo:

```js
const arr1 = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
const test1 = arr1.every((num) => num > 10); // verifica se cada elemento é maior que 10
console.log(test1); //=> true

const arr2 = [9, 12, 13, 14, 15];
const test2 = arr2.every((num) => num > 10); // verifica se cada elemento é maior que 10
console.log(test2); //=> false
```

Então, você pode usar esse método.

Apenas atente-se que, como você tem um conjunto de dados com “profundidade” de dois arrays, terá que aninhar duas chamadas à `every`. Mais ou menos assim:

```js
const materials = [
  {
    group: 'A',
    data: [
      { id: 1, name: 'PC Dell', materialGroup: 'A', amount: 1, status: false },
      { id: 2, name: 'Mouse', materialGroup: 'A', amount: 2, status: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    group: 'B',
    data: [
      { id: 3, name: 'Teclado', materialGroup: 'B', amount: 1, status: false }
    ]
  }
];

const result = materials.every((material) =>
  material.data.every((entry) => !entry.status)
);
console.log(result);
```

---

Não tem muito a ver com a pergunta, mas repare:

- [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) verifica se o predicado é verdadeiro para *todos* os elementos do array.
- [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) verifica se o predicado é verdadeiro para *pelo menos um* dos elementos do array.

Comment: E ae Felipe, blz? Cara, me tira uma dúvida: achei legal esse `every`, mas imagino que ele irá analisar cada item da array pra verificar os valores, não? Será que um `forEach` não seria, pelo menos teoricamente, mais performático? Digo isso porque com `forEach` é possível parar o laço assim que um valor não satisfazer a condição, dispensando que se analise tudo. Valeu!

Comment: @Sam, o `every` para a varredura assim que o primeiro predicado avalia `false` (caso contrário, assumindo que todos retornem `true`, varre tudo, tal como esperado). Esse comportamento é previsto pela especificação. Veja [aqui](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-array.prototype.every).

Comment: Ah, legal. Pela lógica, ele deveria parar mesmo, senão ficaria meio sem sentido e a implementação desse método seria "burra" rsrs... valeu!

Comment: @Sam Eu acho que com `forEach` é pior, pois segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach): "*There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method is the wrong tool*" - e logo a seguir é recomendado o uso de `every`, `some`, etc. Na verdade a alternativa seria um `for` simples, esse sim mais performático por não ter as chamadas dos *callbacks*: https://jsbench.me/7ukt1mbwe0/1 (mas pra arrays pequenos a diferença é desprezível)

Comment: @hkotsubo Ah, legal. Só que o `forEach` vc consegue parar com um `return`, claro, dentro de uma exceção (`if`). Realmente um `for` simples seria melhor mesmo.